# Call an overridden method in my main class

Tags: java, methods, overriding

My code is like this...
but there seems to be a problem when I call the overridden method createHome(). Here is a sample code:

```
public class Test extends SweetHome3D {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    new Test().init(args);
    ***createHome();***
  }

  @Override
  public Home createHome() {
    Home home = super.createHome();
    // Modify home as you wish here
    return home;
  }
}
```

Comment: An IDE such as Eclipse will point out such errors!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it that code didn't compile? You are calling `createHome()` as if it's a static method.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
  Test test = new Test();
  test.init(args);
  test.createHome();
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean: 

      Home newhome = new Home();
        newhome.init(args);
        newhome.createHome();

write? Still, it doesn't work:(

Comment: @Mitsaki: No, I mean what I wrote. What you have there would create a `Home` object, and its `createHome()` method would be invoked. The declaration can be `Home`, though. I just wasn't sure whether `init()` was a method of `Home`. What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, this was a part of my code and I was confused. I forgot that I "called" my class here as "Test". You were right, this is the way to do it:) Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @Mitsaki: So it worked? Good :). Make sure to accept this answer ;).